# Where does Meteor's installer put node and npm?

Tags: meteor

I just started learning Meteor JS on a fresh copy of OSX. I used the Meteor install instructions to install it. Everything works well - I can install Meteor packages and run the local instance. But where is Node.js and npm? I assume it must be installed with Meteor because everything runs, but the npm and node command is not available. Am I supposed to install Node separately?

Thanks,

Kevin N.

Edit: Corrected npm in the question title which OS X keeps changing to nom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `METEOR@1.1.0.2`, `node` and `npm` are stored in :

```
/home/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.3/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/
```

(The path depends on both the username and architecture of course).

If you're doing only Meteor dev, you won't need node on its own, you might however need `npm` to install Meteor related tools such as Meteor Up (`mup`), in which case you need to install `npm` separately or alias the command to use the Meteor one.